# Making domain-name only accessible web server with apache2

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, dns, apache-virtualhost, virtual-host

I have a domain name `example.com` and a VPS with a static IP address `123.123.123.123`.
I want the browsers to provide the domain name to access the website content.

In pratice I want people see my website only if they put `exemple.com` and not `123.123.123.123` on their browser's url bar.

So in my `/var/www/` directory I made two subdirectories. 
`/var/www/default` (for the content that those who do not provide the dn will see) 
and 
`/var/www/exemple` for the actual website content.
I edited my `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` file like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias example.com

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/exemple

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In my mind this should work. In pratice the server gives me the content of `/var/www/default` both if i put `123.123.123.123` and `exemple.com` in my browser's url bar. 
Why?

Comment: You cannot have the ServerName and ServerAlias with the same name. What happens if you delete ServerAlias?

Comment: You _can_, it's just pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache will direct traffic to the *first* matching `VirtualHost` which it sees in the configuration.  Because the first one defined does not define a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias`, it's configured to catch any traffic to any bound hostname or any bound IP address on port 80.

Comment: So basically it's not possible to have a different virtual host in the case the browser doesn' give a "Host" header?

Comment: `ServerName 123.123.123.123`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to name the VirtualHost dedicated to example.com. Here are my modifications (with some added suggestions):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/default
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>                              # <= Should fix your issue
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com                               # <= Suggested modification

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/exemple

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error-example.log              # <= Suggested modification
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access-example.log combined   # <= Suggested modification
</VirtualHost>
```

Of course, don't forget to reload Apache.

Comment: You are right. Fixed.